# Python - Pandas read_excel to array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, pandas, list, numpy

Im converting data from excel to Python using Pandas
This data:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mG7ZB.png)
Like that:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/auz5c.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/612OM.png)
And then a want to convert it to array to use Numpy on it. Like that:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jypP6.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3r23Q.png)
I don't know why but every element in an array is in bruckets. This messesd up my code because when i try to check for zero-crossings with Numpy is allways an empty array [ ].
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rkklb.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Dz7U.png)

Im exoect to convert pd.read_excel data to and np.array and the check for zero crossing.
I was trying to mess with indexing and converting every pd.read_excel element indyvidualy using for loop.

Comment: The Pandas `read_excel` returns DataFrame or dict of DataFrames... Check this... Tip: if `dane2` is a DataFrame, then use `dane3 = dane2.to_numpy()`. You can read more: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html